# How to detect if a 2D array is inside another 2D array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, detection

So with the help of a stack-overflow member, I have the following code:

```
data = "needle's (which is a png image) base64 code goes here"
decoded = data.decode('base64')
f = cStringIO.StringIO(decoded)
image = Image.open(f)
needle = image.load()

while True:
    screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()
    haystack = screenshot.load()
    if detectImage(haystack, needle):
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
```

I've written the following code to check if the needle is in the haystack:

```
def detectImage(haystack, needle):
    counter = 0
    for hayrow in haystack:
        for haypix in hayrow:
            for needlerow in needle:
                for needlepix in needlerow:
                    if haypix == needlepix:
                        counter += 1

    if counter == 980: #the needle has 980 pixels
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The issue is that I get this error for line 3: 'PixelAccess' object is not iterable

It was suggested to me that it would be easier to copy both needle and haystack into a numpy/scipy array. And then I can just use a function that checks to see if the 2D array needle is inside the 2D array haystack.

I need help with:

1) converting those arrays to numpy arrays.

2) a function that checks to see if the 2D array needle is inside the 2D array haystack. My function doesn't work.

These are the images:
Needle:
[image: needle]

Haystack:
[image: haystack]
[image: haystack]

Comment: Perhaps this line: `for x1 in haystack[0]:` should say `for x1 in y1:`. and `for x2 in needle[0]:` should be `for x2 in y2:`?  Otherwise you're ignoring the `y` variables (but maybe that's intentional).

Comment: Oh opps. You're right.

Comment: Remember that `for ___ in 2dobject` will give you rows.  A better naming convention might be `for hayrow in haystack ... for haypix in hayrow`

Comment: What does the pix in haypix stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `matchTemplate` in opencv to detect the position:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

needle = cv2.imread("needle.png")
haystack = cv2.imread("haystack.jpg")

diff = cv2.matchTemplate(haystack, needle, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
x, y = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(diff), diff.shape)

pl.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
im = pl.imshow(haystack[:,:, ::-1])
ax = pl.gca()
ax.add_artist(pl.Rectangle((y, x), needle.shape[1], needle.shape[0],  transform=ax.transData, alpha=0.6))
```

here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Currently downloading OpenCV. In the meantime, how would I know if it has found a match or not? By looking at the diff value, right? There is probably some threshold, correct?

Comment: the TM_CCOEFF_NORMED value of  perfect match will be 1. You can use some threshold such as 0.9.

Comment: Getting this error: NameError: name 'Rectangle' is not defined :(

Comment: change it to `pl.Rectangle`.

Comment: cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED is always 3 for some reason. Even if I change images.

Comment: `cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED` is a flag that tell `matchTemplate` to calculate the `CCORR_NORMED` value between the image and the template. `np.max(diff)` will give you the max value. Compare this value to the threshold.

Comment: Thanks! =] Got mixed up with the two names.

Answer (score 3):

To convert the image into a numpy array, you should be able to simply do this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

needle = Image.open('needle.png')
haystack = Image.open('haystack.jpg')

needle = np.asarray(needle)
haystack = np.asarray(haystack)
```

To get you started with finding the needle, note that this will give you a list of all the places where the corner matches:

```
haystack = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,1,3]])
needle = np.array([[2,1],[1,3]])

np.where(haystack == needle[0,0])
#(array([0, 1, 2]),   row-values
# array([1, 1, 0]))   col-values
```

Then, you can look at all the corner matches, and see if the subhaystack there matches:

```
h,w = needle.shape
rows, cols = np.where(haystack == needle[0,0])
for row, col in zip(rows, cols):
    if np.all(haystack[row:row+h, col:col+w] == needle):
        print "found it at row = %i, col = %i"%(row,col)
        break
else:
    print "no needle in haystack"
```

Below is a more robust version that finds the best match, and if it matches better than some percentage, considers the needle found.  Returns the corner coordinate if found, `None` if not.

```
def find_needle(needle, haystack, tolerance=.80):
    """ input:  PIL.Image objects
        output: coordinat of found needle, else None """

    # convert to grayscale ("L"uminosity) for simplicity.
    needle = np.asarray(needle.convert('L'))   
    haystack = np.asarray(haystack.convert('L'))

    h,w = needle.shape
    H,W = haystack.shape
    L = haystack.max()

    best = (None, None, 1)
    rows, cols = np.where((haystack - needle[0,0])/L < tolerance)
    for row, col in zip(rows, cols):
        if row+h > H or col+w > W: continue # out of range
        diff = np.mean(haystack[row:row+h, col:col+w] - needle)/L
        if diff < best[-1]:
            best = (diff, row, col)

    return best if best[-1] < tolerance else None
```

Comment: Needle: http://s24.postimg.org/f8fmxkqg1/needle.png Haystack: http://s1.postimg.org/th80b1a26/haystack.jpg Yes, the needle is entirely in the haystack.

Comment: This still doesn't find the needle image in your haystack image, but I believe that's because one is a jpg and perhaps the lossiness of the jpg distorts it a bit.

Comment: Oh wow. I was just about to give up. Thanks! Will test and provide results.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to be working. http://pastebin.com/L5j0x2GD https://mega.co.nz/#!BcYGgQRQ!ejm8WngiKOcwJikXQGW6AXnhF7B8NJLvTsxwMlK9mGE https://mega.co.nz/#!RJhSXRRA!Ei0jghu2E-z9_MX9wr7q0A83YudKDTL9kRBS--FNGwk It seems to loop forever.

Comment: It's possible that it's just very slow, since it's comparing many subarrays.  My method really isn't suited for comparison of images, sorry.  It would work better for integer arrays.  Try @HYRY's solution.  Another method would be to use `needle` as a kernel and find the max of the convolution.

Comment: @askewchan Tried the convolution way, doesn't work: white areas of the haystack image (so `[255, 255, 255]`) give the largest values of the convolution.

Comment: @Jaime: In general the convolution method works well, at least in my experience, but you need to normalize. Convolution, btw, is one of the ways that OpenCV's `matchTemplate` works.. all of which are just simple equations that are a few lines in numpy: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html

Comment: @tom10 Maybe I messed up with some factor, because I actually did the cross correlation myself using FFTs. But while I managed to create a local maximum close to the right place, the global maxima where elsewhere. I was basically doing `CV_TM_CCORR`, tried also but didn't figure out how to do `CV_TM_SQDIFF`. The way they are defined on the docs, it seems to me that the normalized formulas  are just scaling the result globally, so the maxima will not change, right?

Comment: @Jamie: I think that the sums for normalization are over the primed coordinates, so they are still different for each point.  The two you point out are specifically not normalized.  How about CV_TM_CORR_NORMED, and CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED?

Comment: @Jaime can you post your solution as an answer?  I'm curious to see more detail.

Comment: @askewchan I've added it as an answer. It does work, but it doesn't seem to be very robust. I haven't tried to figure out the normalized versions.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to make a numpy-only implementation of a cross correlation search work... The cross-correlation is calculated using the [cross-correlation theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cross-CorrelationTheorem.html) and FFTs.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def cross_corr(a, b):
    a_rows, a_cols = a.shape[:2]
    b_rows, b_cols = b.shape[:2]
    rows, cols = max(a_rows, b_rows), max(a_cols, b_cols)
    a_f = np.fft.fft2(a, s=(rows, cols), axes=(0, 1))
    b_f = np.fft.fft2(b, s=(rows, cols), axes=(0, 1))
    corr_ab = np.fft.fft2(a_f.conj()*b_f, axes=(0,1))
    return np.rint(corr_ab / rows / cols)

def find_needle(haystack, needle, n=10):
    # convert to float and subtract 128 for better matching
    haystack = haystack.astype(np.float) - 128
    needle = needle.astype(np.float) - 128
    target = np.sum(np.sum(needle*needle, axis=0), axis=0)
    corr_hn = cross_corr(haystack, needle)
    delta = np.sum(np.abs(corr_hn - target), axis=-1)
    return np.unravel_index(np.argsort(delta, axis=None)[:n],
                            dims=haystack.shape[:2])

haystack = np.array(Image.open('haystack.jpg'))
needle = np.array(Image.open('needle.png'))[..., :3]
plt.imshow(haystack, interpolation='nearest')
dy, dx = needle.shape[:2]
candidates = find_needle(haystack, needle, 1)
for y, x in zip(*candidates):
    plt.plot([x, x+dx, x+dx, x, x], [y, y, y+dy,y+dy, y], 'g-', lw=2)
plt.show()
```

So the highest scoring point is the real needle:

[image]

```
>>> print candidates
(array([553], dtype=int64), array([821], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: +1: Thanks for posting this! It's great to have numpy version of subimage matching posted on SO. I'd be interested to hear about why it now works, especially regarding white pixels vs matched pixels, etc.

Comment: @tom10 A lot of it was getting my cross-correlation theorem applied properly, and dealing with int overflows when computing the target value with the `np.sum(needle**2)`. But for it to actually work, the big trick was to not cross correlate the images, but the images - 128. There are still a large number of images that will give the same result for the cross correlation, but apparently not so many. Without that trick, the real needle is something like the 100th best match... Frankly, I don't think the algorithm, as described above, is very robust.

Comment: @tom10 It does work perfectly with binary images, if you search in `2*image - 1`.