# Find image inside another in SimpleCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, simplecv

I'm using Python and SimpleCV (but is ok to use OpenCV too) and i have an image:

[image]

Futhermore, i have some small images, like this, which were cropped from the original image:

[image]

Assuming that the first image contains the second, I would like to get the second's image coordinates in regard of first, before cropping. How I can make this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711019/how-to-detect-if-a-2d-array-is-inside-another-2d-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [matchTemplate](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html) in OpenCV:

```
diff = cv2.matchTemplate(img1, img2, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
x, y = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(diff), diff.shape)
```